# Problems with quad when using lambdify

Tags: sympy, lambdify, symbolic-integration

I'm trying to solve these two integrals, I want to use a numerical approach because C_i will eventually become more complicated and I want to use it for all cases. Currently, C_i is just a constant so _quad is not able to solve it. I'm assuming because it is a Heaviside function and it is having trouble finding the a,b. Please correct me if I'm approaching this wrongly.

[image]

Equation 33

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...: import scipy as sp
   ...: import sympy as smp
   ...: from sympy import DiracDelta
   ...: from sympy import Heaviside

In [2]: C_i = smp.Function('C_i')

In [3]: t, t0, x, v = smp.symbols('t, t0, x, v', positive=True)

In [4]: tot_l = 10

In [5]: C_fm = (1/tot_l)*v*smp.Integral(C_i(t0), (t0, (-x/v)+t, t))

In [6]: C_fm.doit()
Out[6]: 
0.1*v*Integral(C_i(t0), (t0, t - x/v, t))

In [7]: C_fm.doit().simplify()
Out[7]: 
0.1*v*Integral(C_i(t0), (t0, t - x/v, t))

In [8]: C_fms = C_fm.doit().simplify()

In [9]: t_arr = np.arange(0,1000,1)

In [10]: f_mean = smp.lambdify((x, v, t), C_fms, ['scipy', {'C_i': lambda e: 0.8}])

In [11]: try2 = f_mean(10, 0.1, t_arr)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/ipykernel_3164/3786931540.py", line 1, in <module>
    try2 = f_mean(10, 0.1, t_arr)

  File "<lambdifygenerated-1>", line 2, in _lambdifygenerated
    return 0.1*v*quad(lambda t0: C_i(t0), t - x/v, t)[0]

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 348, in quad
    flip, a, b = b < a, min(a, b), max(a, b)

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Equation 34

```
In [12]: C_i = smp.Function('C_i')

In [13]: t, tao, x, v = smp.symbols('t, tao, x, v', positive=True)

In [14]: I2 = v*smp.Integral((C_i(t-tao))**2, (tao, 0, t))

In [15]: I2.doit()
Out[15]: 
v*Integral(C_i(t - tao)**2, (tao, 0, t))

In [16]: I2.doit().simplify()
Out[16]: 
v*Integral(C_i(t - tao)**2, (tao, 0, t))

In [17]: I2_s = I2.doit().simplify()

In [18]: tao_arr = np.arange(0,1000,1)

In [19]: I2_sf = smp.lambdify((v, tao), I2_s, ['scipy', {'C_i': lambda e: 0.8}])

In [20]: try2 = I2_sf(0.1, tao_arr)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/ipykernel_3164/4262383171.py", line 1, in <module>
    try2 = I2_sf(0.1, tao_arr)

  File "<lambdifygenerated-2>", line 2, in _lambdifygenerated
    return v*quad(lambda tao: C_i(t - tao)**2, 0, t)[0]

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 351, in quad
    retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 463, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sympy/core/expr.py", line 345, in __float__
    raise TypeError("Cannot convert expression to float")

TypeError: Cannot convert expression to float
```

Comment: I like to see some intermediate results, especially in sympy.  If I can't run the code in my head, tben I have to copy-n-paste and run it on the computer to see what's happenning.  And I'm too lazy to do that - unless the question is clear and my curiousity is raised.

Comment: @hpaulj Just added the intermediate results and errors that it is showing

Answer (score 0):

So you are passing an unevaluated `Integrate` to `lambdify`, which in turn translates it call to `scipy.integrate.quad`.

Looks like the integrals can't be evaluated even with `doit` and `simplify` calls.  Have you actually looked at `C_fms` and `I2_s`?  That's one of the first things I'd do when running this code!

I've never looked at this approach.  I have seen people `lambdify` the objective expression, and then try to use that in `quad` directly.

`quad` has specific requirements (check the docs!).  The objective function must return a single number, and the bounds must also be numbers.

In the first error, you are passing array `t_arr` as the `t` bound, and it got the usual `ambiguity` error when checking where it is bigger than the other bound, `0`.  That's that `b < a` test.  `quad` cannot use arrays as bounds.

I not sure why the second case gets avoids this problem - bounds must be coming from somewhere else.  But the error comes when `quad` calls the objective function, and expects a float return.  Instead the function returns a `sympy` expression which `sympy` can't convert to float.  My guess there's some variable in the expression that's still a `sympy.symbol`.

In diagnosing `lambdify` problems, it's a good idea to look at the generated code.  One way is with `help` on the function,  `help(I2_sf)`.  But with that you need to be able to read and understand python, including any `numpy` and `scipy` functions.  That's not always easy.

Have you tried to use `sympy's` own numeric integrator?  Trying to combine `sympy` and `numpy/scipy` often has problems.